# Creating HCl acid

Tags: reaction-mechanism, aqueous-solution

I have the following reaction:

$$\ce{2 AlCl3 + 3H2O -> 2 Al(OH)3 + 6 HCl}$$

My goal is to create hydrochloric acid, but for the reaction shown, hydrochloride gas is produced instead. There are two scenarios that I am facing where:

- The aluminum chloride is an aqueous solution instead of a solid
- The aluminum chloride is a solid after heating the aqueous solution and the result is water vapor and solid $\ce{AlCl3}$.

My confusion and questions are that:

- If I had an aqueous solution that is $\ce{AlCl3}$ in water, then why does it not react in the first place?
- Does the water in the product side need to be a liquid, an aqueous solution, or a gas?
- How do I make sure that the reaction works nearly every time?
- I am trying to create hydrochloric acid meaning that $\ce{HCl}$ needs to react with water to provide a concentration of $\ce{HCl}$ acid. Would the water need to be a gas in order for both $\ce{HCl}$ and water to condense to hydrochloric acid or is there something else that I missed?
- Is there a way that if I added more water to $\ce{AlCl3}$ that I would get $\ce{HCl}$ acid instead of gas?

I know that there are other methods of producing $\ce{HCl}$ acid, but I want to use this method.

Comment: There's no such thing as "hydrochloric gas"; it's either "hydrochloric acid" for $\ce{HCl (aq)}$, or "hydrogen chloride [gas]" for $\ce{HCl (g)}$. On a side note, you can also check out [FAQ: How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry Stack Exchange?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/16683) to see how to write chemical equations here.

Comment: I meant to say hydrochloride gas.

Comment: Not really, it's hydrogen chloride, not hydrochloride.

Comment: By solid AlCl3, do you mean hexahydrate or anhydrous form? Their behavior in contact with water differ significantly, especially at low water/compound ratios, when anhydrous chloride undergoes dramatic hydrolysis with HCl fumes. The anhydrous one cannot be formed by dehydration of hexahydrate, hydrolysing during the process, producing HCl fumes. // Produced HCl would be either too diluted either contaminated by aluminium chloride.

Comment: Why produce a cheap substance ($\ce{HCl}$) from a more expensive substance like $\ce{AlCl3}$ ?

Comment: @Maurice That I wondered about too, like transmutation of copper to iron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per this source](http://www.rod.beavon.org.uk/AlCl3_and_water.htm), a good account of the actual product of dissolving $\ce{AlCl3}$ in a large volume of water:

> If aluminium chloride is dissolved in a large amount of water the solution is acidic, but this has nothing to do with formation of hydrochloric acid. The solution contains hydrated aluminium ions and chloride ions:

> $\ce{AlCl3(s) + aq -> [Al(H2O)6]^3+(aq) + 3Cl^-(aq)}$

> The hexaqua complex ion behaves exactly like ions of similar type formed from transition metals; the small, highly charged metal ion polarises (withdraws electron density from) the water molecules that are attached to the aluminium ion through dative covalent bonds. This makes the hydrogen atoms d+ and susceptible to attack from solvent water, which is acting as a base. The complex ion is deprotonated, causing the solution to be acidic from the formation of hydroxonium ions $\ce{H3O+}$:

> $\ce{[Al(H2O)6]^3+ (aq) + H2O(l) ->  [Al(H2O)5OH]^2+(aq) + H3O+(aq)}$

So, no $\ce{HCl}$ per se, but adding a small amount of water to the dry salt will liberate fumes of hydrogen chloride that readily dissolve in water forming aqueous $\ce{HCl}$, but not likely a practical path either.

In my opinion, however, try adding $\ce{AlCl3}$ to a large volume of carbonated water as a [possible path](https://pubs.usgs.gov/wsp/1827a/report.pdf) to very dilute $\ce{HCl}$. I expect the intermediate formation of an [unstable aluminum carbonate](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/article-abstract/251550) followed by the deposition of $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ (interestingly, this reaction mirrors the wrong commonly cited hydrolysis reaction forming $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ and $\ce{HCl}$). Note, quickly separate the solid to limit the reverse reaction recreating the $\ce{AlCl3}$. This reaction, if successful, may also be viewed as paralleling the action of oxalic acid on various salts of mineral acids, successfully forming the mineral acid, along with a corresponding insoluble oxalate (there exists a thread on this).

Comment: *Hint* regarding [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/), for future reference: On occasion, copy-paste from other sources into mhchem syntax drops «some of the (implicit) accidentals» to indicate subscript (mhchem describes with leading underscore) or superscript (by leading caret).  For a single plus sign (like in `$\ce{Na+}$`) this isn't problematic.  However, e.g., a dash with leading caret becomes an superscript minus, and without leading caret extends like a single bond to the next atom.  And arrows are more portable if composed with `<`, `>` and either `-` or `=`, too.

Comment: For those curious on my reference to a work on aluminum complex formation, it is because there is amazing effort to avoid any CO2/carbonate contamination. If this implies an issue with aluminum complex formation, and we are interested in other reactions, then it is possibly supportive.  Note: the alluded to CO2 > H2O > HCO3- > Aluminum carbonate > Al(OH)3 and CO2 release has a cyclic aspect so a small amount of CO2 impurity in time can apparently be problematic with aqueous AlCl3, for example.